Error 403: Access Sharepoint using App Credentials in Python
I am trying to access files stored in SharePoint using Python. I have registered the app in Azure Ad and have client_id and client_secret. I have given the read and write permissions however I am still getting 403 error.
I am not really sure as to what I am missing out on. below is the script:
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential

site_url = ''
app_principal = {
    'client_id': '',
    'client_secret': ''
}

credentials = ClientCredential(app_principal['client_id'], app_principal['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(credentials)

web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()

I also tried modifying permissions but it didn't work.

Could you please include API permissions image of your application from Portal by editing your question to check what permissions you granted?

I don't have access to AD. The Admin is handling but they gave read and write access

Please check below added answer and confirm with your admin whether they added same permissions in similar way or not.

The error usually occurs if the application does not have required permissions to perform the operation.
To access SharePoint with app-only principal, run below URL and sign in with Global Administrator credentials to add permissions for Azure AD application:
https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

You can find your application by entering  AppId  and use below xml for adding permissions:
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>


In the next step, click on Trust it option to grant permissions to app-only principal:

I have one SharePoint document library named doclib with few files in it as below:

When I ran below Python code to list files present in above SharePoint document library, I got the response successfully like this:
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential

# SharePoint site and credentials
site_url = 'https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sridemosite'
app_principal = {
    'client_id': 'appId',
    'client_secret': 'secret'
}

credentials = ClientCredential(app_principal['client_id'], app_principal['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(credentials)

# Load web and print its title
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))

# Function to list all files in a document library
def list_files(folder_url):
    folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_url)
    files = folder.files
    ctx.load(files)
    ctx.execute_query()

    for file in files:
        print(f"File name: {file.properties['Name']}")

# Specify the document library to list files from
document_library_url = "/sites/sridemosite/doclib"
list_files(document_library_url)

Response:

Reference:
python - Sharepoint Rest API office365 library 403 Client Error - Stack Overflow
